# Purpose of pooling layer after text embedding layer

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I'm following the tutorial on the tensorflow site (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word_embeddings#create_a_simple_model) to learn word embeddings, and a confusion that I have is about the purpose of having a Globalaveragepooling layer right after the embedding layer as follows:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
  layers.Embedding(encoder.vocab_size, embedding_dim),
  layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
  layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(1)
])
```

I understand what pooling means and how it's done. If someone can explain why we need a pooling layer, and what would change if we didn't use it, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of this tutorial is to get you to understand word-embeddings through a simple toy task: binary sentiment analysis.

To start with, they make you code a simple model: take the average of all embeddings in a sentence and add a feed-forward neural net to classify this aggregated input. `GlobalAveragePooling1D` does this averaging.

Obviously in the real world you'd want to use more complex models as RNNs, LSTMs, bidirectional models, atrous-convolution-based models or Transformers but that's not the point in this tutorial.

The "simple model" they mention being a feed-forward neural net, it expects a fixed input dimension so when you have sequential data of variable length you need to address this somehow: averaging, padding, cropping etc. Here they average with this `GlobalAveragePooling1D` layer

Comment: By taking average of all embeddings, you mean we're taking the average of the embeddings of all the words in the sentence to arrive at "average meaning" for the sentence ? Also, can you add some details about the dimensions in each layer and how the dimensions are carried from the first layer to the last ?

Comment: wanted to nudge you if you could please see my last comment. Thanks for your time.